# JQUERY - send serialized data through .load function

Tags: jquery, serialization, load

Can I send already serialized data through .load function to loaded file?
I know i can use .ajax() function and put serialized data to 'data:' part but i'm curious is that possible to send somehow data like this:

```
param = 'txt1=1&txt2=2'
.load('file.html', param, function() { [...] })
```

instead of

```
.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: param,
  success: function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it would be closer to this:

```
.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: param,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(){}
});
```

Check out what jQuery is doing behind the scenes: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=load

Comment: but  it's still larger form using type: url: data: - i guess load just doesnt accept serialized data like .ajax does. thanx anyway.

Comment: @Kalreg, no load is simply shorthand for AJAX. So they are basically the same. But to clearify, I am saying use load not get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `data` is an optional second argument for [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

Comment: What have you tried? I use serialized data all the time when using load to retrieve certain information from a remote page.

Comment: The serialized version will trigger a `GET` request. Kalreg may be explicitly trying to `POST` the serialized string...which I don't believe will work without a little massaging.